# Logistic Regression or Linear Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, matlab

Say I have the following hypothetical scenario:

I have a material that I can freely configure, starting with 10 different strength properties.

```
MTRL = 1.4:0.2:3.2;
```

Next, pretend that I've smashed them 5 times each and recorded the % of the material that was damaged, giving me a vector of smash results that is 50-by-1 (5 multiplied by 10). Let's say the range of % damaged is between 40-100%.

I'd like to do a logistic regression (in case it is non-linear) to find a strength level corresponding to the 75% damage point except that % damage is not categorical which gives me an error in MATLAB. Is logistic regression still appropriate or would a GLM work better?

Comment: Ordinarily, people understand "logistic regression" to be a particular kind of generalized linear model (GLM).  Since you contrast these two, please tell us exactly what you mean by "logistic regression".

Comment: What is the objective of the analysis? To predict the percentage of failure a particular smash may cause *conditional or unconditional* of the previous amount of failure? To predict the *number* of smashes needed to cause 100% failure of a material (or perhaps 50% or lower?) Is the strength of each smash consistent? Did you measure smash strength?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with linear regression is that you are modelling E(Y/X) directly, so predicted values in theory can be <0 or >1. 
With logistic regression you are using a link function that prevent values to fall outside the range of (0;1).

You need your response to be either binary or ordinal, so you should create levels, I suggest using the quantiles of that percent and adjust a cumulative logistic regression. If you are only interested in two groups of values for the percentage - let's say <75 or >75%, then use the logistic regression for binary outcomes.

An example of logistic regression with ordinal data can be followed [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm).
For a binary outcome, see [this one](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a fractional logit model, which can be implemented as a GLM with binomial family, a logit link, and heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors. This can accomodate your outcome if you divide it by 10 to put it on a [0,1] scale.

Comment: If you downvoted this, can you please elaborate on why? I'd like to know what I can improve?